# What is this information of midiAccessInterface

Tags: midi, web-midi

I'm implementing the Web-MIDI API on Chrome and I list all my inputs devices into a simple table bootstrap. I have a MOTU Midi Express XT interface MIDI on my computer. Why I have this information display ?

What means the version and why manufacturer is Microsoft ?

[image]

The name is displayed like other music tools on my computer but not for the manufacturer...

Answer (score 0):

The interface between applications and MIDI kernel drivers is a driver/DLL written by Microsoft (wdmaud.drv/wdmaud.sys). Chrome's Web MIDI implementation takes the information from there, so the manufacturer and version is the same for all those ports.